# How to catch DataGridView validation Error when I write value in editable cells?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I've seen a lot of solutions for this where data binding is involved, but I don't have a data source. In this case the combo cell only applies to 1 row (other rows don't have the DataGridViewComboBoxCell).

I set a DataGridViewComboCell up like this:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
cell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;
cell.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());   // items is List<string>
```

And I dynamically re-populate it later like this:

```
_cell.Items.Clear();
_cell.Items.AddRange(this.Data.ResponseOptions.Select( d => d.Description).ToArray());   
//d.Description is of type string
```

But then I get this nasty dialog that says:

> The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:
>   System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.
>   To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.

It doesn't help much, by the way, to say it is not "valid". Is it fair to send an email to MS saying Windows Forms is not valid?

I've tried grabbing the cell's items property and adding the strings using a foreach() with an Add() call. I still get the dialog.

I've also tried blowing away the entire cell everytime I want to update it and recreating a new DataGridViewComboCell from scratch. I still get the dialog.

I've also tried manually overwriting the columns value (succeeds when I don't have this problem). Didn't fix it, though.

I only seem to get this dialog when I'm trying to repopulate the items in the combo cell.

For now I just wiped out the DataError method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have seen this error before. It occurs when you have set a *ValueType* for the cell and the data you feed are of different type. Have you checked that?

Comment: @ThunderGr: that's what I thought also, but as you can see from above I've tried adding the items as exactly the same type initially and in the update (in several ways).

Comment: If I were you, I would have DataError print me a report on a messagebox of the type and values of items that are added. Many times what you *think* you do, is not the same as what you *actually* do. Especially in C#. I suspect nulls, to tell the truth.

Comment: Did you try to have the DataError print you the values and types they caused it to fire? It is the most likely shot you have. DataError fires *for each value that is invalid*. If it fires only once for you, then there is *only one value* that is invalid. Also, the problem could be on the text value of the combo. Not in the list of values.

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit old but I ran into this and it turns out that ThunderGR absolutely had it right.  When I had DataError print a report I began to look at the values in the database and noticed that they actually were in all CAPS.  Simply changed my string values to all caps and no longer received the error.

Here is a way of possibly handling the DataError although I'd rather not have it fired in the first place.

```
    private void dataGridView_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Exception.Message == "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.")
            {
                object value = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
                if (!((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex]).Items.Contains(value))
                {
                    ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex]).Items.Add(value);
                }
            }

            throw e.Exception;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bool rethrow = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "UI Policy");
            if (rethrow)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format(@"Failed to bind ComboBox. "
                + "Please contact support with this message:"
                + "\n\n" + ex.Message));
            }
        }
    }
```

This way the value will get added to the items collection but still throw the exception where it can be logged.  I used a messagebox because I still think it is important that the user experience the error message and contact support to have it fixed.  Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

1. Use WPF.
2. Bind the combobox column in the DataGrid to a List.
3. Sing a song - you'll *want* to after you realize how easy this is to implement in WPF!

Comment: Ah, a root cause analysis :) I have the authority to put this in the suggestion box, and that's about it.

Comment: I was wondering if maybe by emptying the combo box that, because the column's value is no longer found in the combo box, it could be causing the error/exception?

Comment: I should have mentioned (1) I also manually overwrite the value and (2) this is just for 1 row in the DGV. Other rows do not have the combo cell.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same exception today, spend lot of time figuring out the issue. It turned out that I had an event handler called when a new row was getting created for the datagridview. In that event handler method, I was incorrectly setting the combobox cell value to a value which does not exists in the items collection of combox box.

So, in short, the exception thrown was showing correct message. I just had to locate where exactly, incorrect value was getting set in.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items, you'll need to set DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource to a List of ResponseOptions, and set DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.ValueType = typeof(ResponseOption).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it adding to the list that I assign to the datasource a item corresponding with the empty item in the combobox.

For instance,

```
var list = controller.GetAllMovementKind();
list.Add(new Model.MovementKind { Code = 0, Name = String.Empty });
movementKindBindingSource.DataSource = list;
```

GetAllMovementKind method return a `List<Model.MovementKind>`

I hope that it help you.

Answer (score 0):

To manage and validate the editable data in DataGridView you add manually the follow event :

```
myDataGridView.DataError += myDataGridView_DataError;
```

and implement the event in this way:

```
private void dataGridApprovazioni_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dataGridView = (DataGridView)sender;
    dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = DateTime.MinValue;
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Date Format", "System Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

}
```

in this example is managed the control od DateTime fiel in e specific colum index.