# How to Set Index of ComboBox in DataGridView Column

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I want to know if there is a way to set index of **ComboBox** that is already in **DataGridView** column. I don't want to add new Column and/or Remove existing one.

Let's say I have four columns (e.g. Employee Info) in **DataGridView** as:

```
ID   |    Name   |   Address   |    Job
```

Now, **Job** attribute is of type **ComboBox** has some known and valid values. I have tried via ***DataTable*** and ***DataGridViewComboBoxCell*** methods but didn't work as required.

What should be done at this point? Here is the code:

```
        dtGridView.Rows.Add();
        dtGridView.Rows[row].Cells["ID"].Value = ID;
        dtGridView.Rows[row].Cells["Name"].Value = Name;
        dtGridView.Rows[row].Cells["Address"].Value = Address;
        // Below Line doesn't work
        dtGridView.Rows[row].Cells["Job"].Value = ????????
```

Keep in mind that dtGridView is Read-Only and value must be assigned via code i.e. set Index of ComboBox.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want to add items to the combo at runtime, or set the value?

Comment: @stuartd: Oops, my mistake... I don't want to add new values just taking any value from within the list.

Comment: What's the datasource of the combo, and what error do you get when you set the value?

Comment: I get error:
_System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid._

Comment: It sounds like the value you're trying to set does not exist in the data source the combo ius bound to, or is the wrong type.

Comment: I know that's type error... Value assigned is of type string while column in of type ComboBox but even if I assign ComboBox Object to it. Still the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128193/discussion-between-miftikhark-and-stuartd).

Comment: There are lots of questions that address this exact error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654829/datagridviewcomboboxcell-binding-value-is-not-valid, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461885/error-datagridviewcomboboxcell-value-is-not-valid-datasource-is-list-of-basi, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503306/datagridviewcomboboxcell-claims-value-is-not-valid etc

Comment: Thanks Man! I tried most of the solutions available on StackOverflow. After reading them I asked this question but still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

**DataGridViewComboBoxColumn** and **DataGridViewComboBoxCell** both together solved my problem. Values are now stored in **Enum** and taking from there for both ComboBoxes on **FORM** and as well as **DataGridViewComboBox**